# Finding matrix of linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

The question is
$L: M_{22}\rightarrow M_{22}$ is the linear transformation defined by

$$L(A)= \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix} A - A \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
1 & 1 \\\end{bmatrix}$$

Find the bases for the kernel and range of L.

Actually I find a matrix L 
$$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -2 & 2 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & -2 \\
0 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\\end{bmatrix}$$ by using elementary matrices

But in the solution L is 
$$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1 & 2 & 0 \\
-2 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & -2 & 0 \\\end{bmatrix}$$.

What is the solution and what did I do wrong?

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the basis for $M_{2,2}$?

How about $e_1 = \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix},e_2 = \begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix},e_3 = \begin{bmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{bmatrix},e_4 = \begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$

$L(e_1) = -2e_2 + e_3\\
L(e_2) = - e_1 + e_4\\
L(e_3) = 2 e_1  -2e_4\\
L(e_4) = 2 e_2 - e_3$

The difference in the matrices depends on the choice of basis.

And the kernel appears to be $e_1+e_4$ and $e_3+2e_2$

Comment: Could you explain your solution more?

Comment: I am not sure what would help.  Swapping the choices of $e_1, e_2, e_3, e_4$ get you from the matrix you created to the one that you have been told is the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

Any matrix $L$ that represents the linear transformation does so with respect to a specific ordered basis. What ordered basis of $M_{22}$ did you use to write down your $L$? Is it possible that the solution used a different ordered basis? You would both still get the same answer once you translated back to subspaces of $M_{22}$.

Comment: I write in the question i used elementary matrices

Comment: The *order* of matrices in an ordered basis matters when writing down the transformation matrix in that ordered basis.